# vim: replace sub-match with the same number of new strings

Tags: vim

My plan is to do a pretty standard search replace, replacing all instances of `old_string` with `new_string`. The problem is that I only want to do this for an arbitrary number of `old_strings` following a specific `prefix`.  So for example:

```
old_string = "a"
new_string = "b"
prefix = "xxxx"

xxxxaaaaaaaa => xxxxbbbbbbbb
xxxxaaapostfix => xxxxbbbpostfix
xxaaaa => xxaaaa
```

etc.  I'm not sure how to do this.  I imagine there's some way to say `s/xxxxa*/xxxxb{number of a's}/g` or something, but I have no idea what it is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can definitely do this! I would use the `\=` register to evaluate some vimscript. From `:h s/\=`:

```
Substitute with an expression           *sub-replace-expression*
                        *sub-replace-\=* *s/\=*
When the substitute string starts with "\=" the remainder is interpreted as an
expression.

The special meaning for characters as mentioned at |sub-replace-special| does
not apply except for "<CR>".  A <NL> character is used as a line break, you
can get one with a double-quote string: "\n".  Prepend a backslash to get a
real <NL> character (which will be a NUL in the file).
```

Then you can use the `repeat` and `submatch` functions to build the right string. For example:

```
:%s/\(xxxx\)\(a\+\)/\=submatch(1).repeat('b', len(submatch(2)))
```

I chose to use `\+` instead of `*` because then the pattern will not be found after the substitute command finished (this effects `hlsearch` and <kbd>n</kbd>)

Of course, if you use the `\zs` and `\ze` (start/end of match) atoms, you can use less capturing groups, which makes this waaay shorter and clearer.

```
:%s/xxxx\zsa\+/\=repeat('b', len(submatch(0)))
```

Comment: will `submatch(1)` be the same as `\1`? i.e. can I use `len(\1)` for brevity?

Comment: @ewok It would give the same result, but you can't use `\1` since it isn't a vimscript function or keyword. The right-hand-side of `\=` must be a valid vimscript expression. Unfortunately, this tends to make `\=` expressions painfully long.

Comment: So I assume there is no built-in way to do this with a simple search/replace pattern, then?

Comment: @ewok No, there isn't. I mean, I suppose you could do `:%s/\vxxxx\zs(a*)a/\1b/g` and just run it until it errors (or in a recursive macro, like `qq:%s/\vxxxx\zs(a*)a/\1b/g<cr>@qq@q`) but that seems pointlessly complicated.

Answer (score 1):

If you have `perl` support, you can use

```
:%perldo s/xxxx\Ka+/"b" x length($&)/ge
```

- `xxxx\Ka+` match one or more `a` only if preceded by `xxxx`
- lookbehind with \K
- `/ge` replace all occurrences in line, `e` allows to use Perl code in replacement section
- `"b" x length($&)` the string `b` repeated `length($&)` number of times

See `:h perl` for more info